# UIButton in UITableViewCell is being reused

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

My tableview displays podcast data. All cells are reused fine and display podcasts in the right order. I add download and play buttons as subviews of each cell. When I scroll down the list, the play button which is meant to be hidden for non-downloaded episodes will be shown and will hold the data of the cell which previously initiated a download. For example if I tap download button in cell 1, it will download the right episode and the play button will play the episode perfectly. If I scroll down to cell 10, the same play button will appear and will play episode from button 1. What's wrong with my code?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
    let cell: PFTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PFTableViewCell
    if let title = object?["title"] as? String {
        cell.textLabel?.text = title
        let downloadButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
        downloadButton.frame = CGRectMake(cell.contentView.bounds.width - 100, cell.contentView.bounds.height / 2, 100, 35)
        downloadButton.setTitle("Download", forState: .Normal)
        downloadButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
        downloadButton.tag = indexPath.row
        downloadButton.addTarget(self, action: "downloadEpisode:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        cell.addSubview(downloadButton)
        let playButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
        playButton.frame = CGRectMake(cell.contentView.bounds.width - 100, cell.contentView.bounds.height - 89, 100, 35)
        playButton.setTitle("Play", forState: .Normal)
        playButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
        playButton.tag = indexPath.row
        playButton.addTarget(self, action: "playEpisode:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        if let isDownloaded = object?["isDownloaded"] as? String {
            if isDownloaded == "yes" {
                playButton.hidden = false
            } else {
                playButton.hidden = true
            }
        }
        cell.addSubview(playButton)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Edit:

I've also tried this but it doesn't work and still creates 1 more button per cell:

```
     override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
    let cell: PFTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PFTableViewCell
    if let title = object?["title"] as? String {
        cell.textLabel?.text = title
    }
        if let button = cell.viewWithTag(indexPath.row) {
            print(button)
        } else {
            if let isDownloaded = object?["isDownloaded"] as? String {
                if isDownloaded == "yes" {
                    let downloadButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
                    downloadButton.frame = CGRectMake(cell.contentView.bounds.width - 100, cell.contentView.bounds.height / 2, 100, 35)
                    downloadButton.setTitle("Play", forState: .Normal)
                    downloadButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
                    downloadButton.tag = indexPath.row
                    downloadButton.addTarget(self, action: "playEpisode:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
                    cell.addSubview(downloadButton)
                } else {
                    let downloadButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
                    downloadButton.frame = CGRectMake(cell.contentView.bounds.width - 100, cell.contentView.bounds.height / 2, 100, 35)
                    downloadButton.setTitle("Download", forState: .Normal)
                    downloadButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
                    downloadButton.tag = indexPath.row
                    downloadButton.addTarget(self, action: "downloadEpisode:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
                    cell.addSubview(downloadButton)
                }
            }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Edit2:

Added download method:

```
        func downloadEpisode(sender: UIButton) {
    print("Downloading..")
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)

    let object = self.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    if let result = object {
    let urlstring = result["downloadURL"] as? String
    if urlstring != nil {
    let episodeURL = NSURL(string: urlstring!)
        downloader.downloadPodcastEpisode(episodeURL!, podcast: result)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer:

Although all answers were right, I have decided to remove the button download/play on cell taps in the end. Many thanks!

Comment: Where do you set the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding a *new* button every time. When your cell is reused, it will already have a button. You need to write code that guarantees a button will only be created once, and after that, modify the existing button instead of creating a new one.

There are two common approaches to this:

- Use `viewWithTag` to check if a button exists (create a button and set its tag if it doesn't)
- Subclass `UITableViewCell`, create the button in the initializer, and configure the button each time the cell is used.

Searching for "uitableviewcell viewwithtag" or "subclass uitableviewcell" should give you plenty of sample code, so I won't rehash that here.

Comment: Updated thread with a potential solution but it still doesn't work

Comment: @user2747220 Don't use `viewWithTag(indexPath.row)`, use the same number every time, like `viewWithTag(123)` and `downloadButton.tag = 123`.

Comment: I can't do that. Please see edited thread. I use the indexPath.row as a tag to identify the tapped cell in my download method.

Comment: Then you'll need to either change that to use a different approach (like delegation) or manage the download button in your table cell subclass (as I mentioned in my answer, and C_X's answer expands on)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because placement of a button in a cell in your code is a one-way street: once a button is added to the cell, it is never removed or made invisible.

You need to add an `else` to your `if` statement to remove the button from the recycled cell, if that button exists.

Better yet, make the button a permanent part of the `"Cell"`, and control its visibility in the same `if` statement: instead of adding the button, make it visible; instead of removing the button, make it invisible. As an added bonus, this would let you set up the visual appearance for your button in interface builder, and set some constraints, which would help avoiding "magic numbers" such as 100, 89, and 35 in the body of your code.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code its clear you are already subclassing `UITableViewCell` and have custom UI, then its recommended add button in side `UITableViewCell` either in initialization or if you have `xib` for `cell` then add `UIButton` in `xib` (via interface builder) and create an `IBOutlet` for newly added button .

Now when a `cell` will be reused you will have that button as well, when cell is being reused its your responsibility to keep its state right (means updating its UI), for that override `prepareForReuse` method inside custom `tableViewCell` class and reset UI of cell, and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can update UI as per new data object.

Comment: Thank you for your help!